# Hidden mount --bind

Tags: filesystems, mount

I found in one of the machines I work with a little extrange thing.

I have some mount --bind done it on my machine that are not listed when I type mount.

Is there any idea to how to list all mounted directories that are not listed in mount?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that neither `mount` nor `/etc/mtab` nor `/proc/mounts` contain information on whether a particular mount operation has been done using the "bind" option.

If you can see the mountpoint (/mnt/tmp2 in the example of your comment) in the output of mount, then it has been mounted succesfully. You should not expect to see "bind" in the output of `mount`.

For the long answer, check out Gilles's very interesting answer (and the comments below it) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18048/list-only-bind-mounts).

Answer (score 0):

`mount` don't display all the mounting points in case of error, or if /etc is in read-only mode (the file cache is /etc/mtab).

To see the mount points do a `cat /proc/mounts`

It is stange that you didn't see the --bind in mtab...

Comment: I think someone has copied the directory which has --bind inside them, for this reason I think I didn't showed when I try mount. Could be possible?

Comment: I just try to mount, and it is not written in /proc/mounts : mkdir /mnt/tmp; mkdir /mnt/tmp2; mount -B /mnt/tmp /mnt/tmp2; grep /tmp /proc/mounts: /dev/disk/by-uuid/418151af-d0bd-478e-ab65-ef6319c94944 /mnt/tmp2 ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
You don't see bind (as mount do), but you see it is mounted